# One-to-One Relationship on ERD

Tags: erd

I have a scenario which I have to model using an ERD, but having difficulty with a few things...

So the one-to-one scenario is as follows:

A single SMS message has a single piece of Message Metadata.
A single piece Message Metadata is associated with only a single SMS Message.

The message basically contains the data regarding the state of certain components on a switch board.

- In Metadata table, is Primary Key needed?
- How would the posting happen? Would 'MessageID' (from the SMS Message table) be used as foreign key in Message Metadata table?

  Table definitions below:
- **SMS Message:** MessageID (pk), UserID (fk), SwitchState (bit),
  MotorState (bit), Priority (int)
- **Message Metadata:** SIM Number (bigint), NameOfSender (varchar), Time
  (time), Date (date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you get a one-one relatiion between sms and metadata.

In the DB, you should get one table only. You should get a Pk for message and that's should be enought.

In JEE, you should use @Embeddable and @Embedded annotations.

There is no way to model that in UML, you can use annotations linked to your class or define a stereotype but if you want to follow the spectification strictly, that's not an easy task.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes more sense now- I will combine into one table.

Comment: Happy to help you @mis396